# PHP DateTime daylight savings

Tags: php

Today at work we had an argument. You register a user and write in the db the date of creation of the account. The PHP.ini is set to utc and writes the date in UTC. The problem is that when you transform the time for every user (they can set it to the Europe/London and some other countries in Europe. So, the argument was do you get a different time depending on your date-time savings or not and is that a problem for the database?

Comment: That'll depend how you're doing the transformation.

Comment: You record a certain point in time, you then let users display it in their timezone of choice and your question is will they see a different time depending on their timezone settings?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are storing in a timestamp column, timezones will not affect your time functions.  This is because timestamp stores an absolute time (Epoch time) representing time elapsed since Jan 1 1970 UTC.  So, all you will have to do is convert your time to/from Epoch time and your timezone in the browser should be localized.  Of course, by storing Epoch time, your times will always be relative to UTC in the database.